# Boson operator algebra - unitary transformation

Tags: matrix-calculus, noncommutative-algebra, adjoint-operators, matrix-exponential

What is the simple way to evaluate

$$ e^{i \alpha n(n-1)}a^{\dagger}  e^{-i \alpha n(n-1)}$$

and

$$ e^{i \alpha n(n-1)}a e^{-i \alpha n(n-1)}$$

where $n=a^\dagger a$ and $a$ and $a^\dagger$ are the boson annihilation/creation operators for bosons and $\alpha$ is a constant?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a physical interpretation of these operators?  (I don't mean $n$, $a$, and $a^\dagger$.  I am curious about the two operators you are asking about.)

Comment: Basically I am trying to rewrite the Hamiltonian of the Bose-Hubbard model in the rotating frame with the onsite interaction....so I have to transform the operators $a$ and $a^\dagger$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can evaluate them on states with definite particle number. Let $|k\rangle$ be a state such that $n|k\rangle=k|k\rangle$. Then

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathrm e^{\mathrm i \alpha n(n-1)}a^\dagger\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i \alpha n(n-1)}|k\rangle
&=&
\mathrm e^{\mathrm i \alpha n(n-1)}a^\dagger\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i \alpha k(k-1)}|k\rangle
\\
&=&
\mathrm e^{\mathrm i \alpha (k+1)k}a^\dagger\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i \alpha k(k-1)}|k\rangle
\\
&=&
\mathrm e^{2\mathrm i \alpha k}a^\dagger|k\rangle
\\
&=&
a^\dagger\mathrm e^{2\mathrm i \alpha n}|k\rangle\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

Since $|k\rangle$ was arbitrary and the states with definite particle number span the state space, this implies

$$
\mathrm e^{\mathrm i \alpha n(n-1)}a^\dagger\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i \alpha n(n-1)}=a^\dagger\mathrm e^{2\mathrm i \alpha n}\;.
$$

Analogously, you can obtain

$$
\mathrm e^{\mathrm i \alpha n(n-1)}a\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i \alpha n(n-1)}=a\mathrm e^{-2\mathrm i \alpha(n-1)}\;.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying much more harder paths without any reasons